# Java - can't notify a waiting thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
System.out.println("Thread state: " + threads[i].getState());
threads[i].notify();
```

Produces the following output:

```
Thread state: WAITING
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
at MyPakc.An.run(An.java:49)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

What is going on? Why can I not notify a sleeping thread?

EDIT: The code for the threads[] class:

```
package Part2;

import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JPanel;



class BThread extends Thread{
    private boolean completedThisIter = false;

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        while (true) {
            completedThisIter = false;
            doStuff()
            System.out.println("Completed iter");
            completedThisIter = true;
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean getCompletedThisIter() {
        return completedThisIter;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here is the code that calls this

```
public synchronized void run(){
// OTHER STUFF
    for (int iter = 0; iter < 1212; ++iter){
        System.out.println("Iter " + iter);
        lastAssignedBallIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
            //System.out.println("Num " + numThreads + "  " + i);
            //ballThreads[i] = new BallThread(ballList.subList(lastAssignedBallIndex+1,lastAssignedBallIndex+numBallsPerThread),
            //        ballPanel);
            //lastAssignedBallIndex += numBallsPerThread;
            System.out.println("State " + ballThreads[i].getState());
            if (ballThreads[i].getState() == Thread.State.NEW) {
                ballThreads[i].start();
            } else { //if (ballThreads[i].getState() == Thread.State.BLOCKED) {
                System.out.println("Thread state: " + ballThreads[i].getState());
                ballThreads[i].notify();
            }
        }
        //try{
            for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
                while (!ballThreads[i].getCompletedThisIter()) {
                    System.out.println("iter:" + iter + " ball:" + i + "  " + ballThreads[i].getCompletedThisIter());
                    //wait(); // TODO elliminate polling here
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Joined");
        //}
       // catch(InterruptedException ie){ie.printStackTrace();}


        ballPanel.repaint();
        notifyAll();
        try{
            Thread.sleep(2);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie){}
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the thread that's waiting?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Notifying the `Thread` object won't cause anything to happen unless there's another thread that has called `wait()` on it.

Comment: Yeah, I am giving you the output of the state before calling notify(), and you see that it is WAITING

Comment: Where's the code that does what it is that you are notifying the thread about? If the thread is waiting for X, then when X happens, you notify it. Where is the X actually happening? And where is that being communicated to the thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing out the state of a `ballThreads[i]` then notifying a `threads[i]`. Not sure if this is intended behavior but you're not allowed to notify a thread when you don't own the object's monitor. Are you sure you're calling this inside a `synchronized()` block for the `threads[i]` object?

---

EDIT:

> Yes, the method that this code is taken out of is synchronized

After your edit to your question, the `synchronized` is on the method, and not the monitor of the object, you need to put your code in a block that looks like this:

```
synchronized(threads[i]) {
    // some stuff
    threads[i].notify();
}
```

The important bit here (as opposed to the `synchronized` keyword in a method declaration) is that you synchronize on an Object, then inside this block, you call `notify()` on *the Object*. Examples:

```
public void run()
{
    synchronized(myObject) {
        // do some stuff
        myObject.notify();
    }
}
```

or

```
public void run()
{
    synchronized(thread1) {
        // do some stuff
        thread1.notify();
    }
}
```

or

```
public void run()
{
    synchronized(syncObject) {
        // do some stuff
        syncObject.notify();
    }
}
```

See the pattern? More info here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Comment: @Trup No, you are synchronizing a method, which uses the object instance as a monitor, **not the object that you are calling `notify()` on** You need to synchronize on the instance of the object that you call `notify()` on.

Comment: @Trup ok, here's a bunch of examples

Comment: Awesome, seems right. But I don't get why sychronizing the whole method didn't work. It only works if I do synchronized(ballThreads[i]) {ballThreads[i].notify();} individually. Why is this? I thought that synchronizing the whole method is a superset of what we're doing here, yet it doesn't do the job

Comment: @Trup When you synchronize a method, the monitor that is used is the instance of the object the method belongs to, not the object that you are calling `notify()` on. You can only call `notify()` when you own the monitor, and you own the monitor if you explicitly synchronize on it. See the link that I posted about locks/syncs, and the previous page that talks about method syncs

Answer (score 1):

`wait()` and `notifiy()` requires that you synchronize on the object that you are waiting on.  if you do a `wait()` and `notify()` on the same object that you used to lock the sync block, then you will get rid of the illegal monitor state exception

Answer (score 1):

You are completely misunderstanding the way the `wait`/`notify` mechanism works. The thread has to decide that there is something it needs to wait for. Then the thread must call `wait`. Then that something has to happen. Then you call `notify` to tell the thread that something happened.

You cannot have the thread call `wait` without first determining that there is something specific that it should wait for. And you cannot call `notify` until something has already happened that the thread needs to be notified about. The something that has happened should be the same thing the thread was checking for when it decided to wait.

The reason you are getting in an error is the synchronization associated with the thing waited for simply doesn't exist which violates the semantics of `wait`/`notify`.

If you're waiting for a mailbox to be non-empty, then you should check if the mailbox is empty, and if so, call `wait`. Make sure you are still inside the mailbox's synchronized routine, otherwise you can't know the mailbox is (still) empty. Then when you put a letter in the mailbox (which has to be inside the mailbox's synchronized routine), you call `notify` to let any waiting threads know the mailbox has changed state. You have to be waiting *for something* the thread can test, such as the state of the mailbox.